# Animating ScaleTransform in Trigger.ExitActions section

Tags: wpf, xaml

I'm trying to set a custom style for buttons in WPF using XAML. I want them to extend their size on mouse hover and go back to original size once not hovered anymore. I also want to use animation for both growing and shrinking to make it look smooth. I am using ScaleTransform and DoubleAnimation for animating ScaleX and ScaleY properties. While the first part is working fine (extending animation on hover), the second part isn't working at all - as soon as I move mu cursor out of the button, it immidiately goes to it's intial state without any animation.

I've tried to animate directly Width and Height properties and it DOES work - however I can't get it working with ScaleTransform.

Here is my App.xaml file where I define the style

```
<Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="GrowOnHover">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">

                    <Setter Property="LayoutTransform">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ScaleTransform ScaleX="1.0" ScaleY="1.0"/>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>

                    <Trigger.EnterActions>
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="LayoutTransform.(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)"
                                                 From="1.0" To="1.1" Duration="0:0:0.5"/>
                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="LayoutTransform.(ScaleTransform.ScaleY)"
                                                 From="1.0" To="1.1" Duration="0:0:0.5"/>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </Trigger.EnterActions>

                    <Trigger.ExitActions>
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="LayoutTransform.(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)"
                                                 From="1.1" To="1.0" Duration="0:0:0.5"/>

                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="LayoutTransform.(ScaleTransform.ScaleY)"
                                                 From="1.1" To="1.0" Duration="0:0:0.5"/>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </Trigger.ExitActions>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
```

and the MainWindow.xaml code where I've put 4 button for the sake of testing.

```
<StackPanel>
        <Button Height="100" Width="200" Margin="10" Content="ASDF"
                Style="{StaticResource GrowOnHover}">

        </Button>

        <Button Height="100" Width="200" Margin="10" Content="ASDF"
                Style="{StaticResource GrowOnHover}">

        </Button>

        <Button Height="100" Width="200" Margin="10" Content="ASDF"
                Style="{StaticResource GrowOnHover}">

        </Button>

        <Button Height="100" Width="200" Margin="10" Content="ASDF"
                Style="{StaticResource GrowOnHover}">

        </Button>
    </StackPanel>
```

I want to have this feature implemented purely in XAML.

Comment: Move the LayoutTransform Setter out of the Trigger into the Button Style.

Comment: It worked, thanks a lot! Guess it's a typical novice mistake - I'm fairly new to WPF technology, especially the XAML part.

Comment: Just in case it isn't clear what happend. The LayoutTransform property value provided by the Setter was only set when the Trigger was active. As soon as IsMouseOver turned to false, the transform was removed and LayoutTransform returned to its default value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below one

```
         <Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="GrowOnHover">
            <Setter Property="LayoutTransform">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ScaleTransform ScaleX="1.0" ScaleY="1.0"/>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Trigger.EnterActions>
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard >
                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="LayoutTransform.(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)"
                                             From="1.0" To="1.1" Duration="0:0:0.5"/>
                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="LayoutTransform.(ScaleTransform.ScaleY)"
                                             From="1.0" To="1.1" Duration="0:0:0.5"/>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </Trigger.EnterActions>

                    <Trigger.ExitActions>
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard >
                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="LayoutTransform.(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)"
                                             From="1.1" To="1.0" Duration="0:0:0.5"/>

                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="LayoutTransform.(ScaleTransform.ScaleY)"
                                             From="1.1" To="1.0" Duration="0:0:0.5"/>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </Trigger.ExitActions>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
```

Comment: Yeah, I already did it, as Clemes suggested in the comment below my post - and it works.

Answer (score -1):

You can use EventTrigger as well

```
  <Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="GrowOnHover">
            <Setter Property="LayoutTransform">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ScaleTransform ScaleX="1.0" ScaleY="1.0"/>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseEnter">
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard >
                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="LayoutTransform.(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)"
                                             From="1.0" To="1.1" Duration="0:0:0.5"/>
                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="LayoutTransform.(ScaleTransform.ScaleY)"
                                             From="1.0" To="1.1" Duration="0:0:0.5"/>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>

                </EventTrigger>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseLeave">
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard >
                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="LayoutTransform.(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)"
                                             From="1.1" To="1.0" Duration="0:0:0.5"/>
                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="LayoutTransform.(ScaleTransform.ScaleY)"
                                             From="1.1" To="1.0" Duration="0:0:0.5"/>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>

                </EventTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
```